# How to display Option menu inside a frame in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display a bunch of `OptionMenu` in tkinter. The problem is that once there are too many `OptionMenu` they go out of screen and they cannot be accessed anymore.

[image]

So I thought of implementing a full-screen scrollbar to solve this.

I followed this tutorial - [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WafQCaok6g&t=0s), in this, the full-screen scrollbar is implemented by putting buttons inside a frame

The code from the tutorial - [Working code with buttons](https://github.com/flatplanet/Intro-To-TKinter-Youtube-Course/blob/master/full_scroll.py)

So I tried to use this code but instead of buttons, use `OptionMenu`.

This is my code

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import ttk



class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.title('ATOM')
        master.geometry('650x650')

        
        main_frame = Frame(root)
        main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # Create A Canvas
        my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
        my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # Add A Scrollbar To The Canvas
        my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
        my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        # Configure The Canvas
        my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
        my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))

        # Create ANOTHER Frame INSIDE the Canvas
        second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)

        # Add that New frame To a Window In The Canvas
        my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")

        length=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        variable_rsi_length = tk.StringVar(second_frame)
        rsi_len = ttk.OptionMenu(second_frame, variable_rsi_length,*length )
        variable_rsi_length.set('14')

        for thing in range(100):
            ttk.Button(second_frame, text=f'Button {thing} Yo!').grid(row=thing, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)


        my_label = Label(second_frame, text="It's Friday Yo!").grid(row=3, column=2)


        rsi_len.pack()
        self.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

But this doesn't give any error on running in fact it does not even show the new window.

How can I implement this?

Comment: There is an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong is that you cannot use `pack` when its children are being managed by `grid`.
To be more specific, the error is: `_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside .!frame.!canvas.!frame which already has slaves managed by grid`

So, what you can easily do is just use one type of geometry manager.
Either use only "pack", or only "grid".

Here's a quick solution:

```
.
.
.

        for thing in range(100):
            ttk.Button(second_frame, text=f'Button {thing} Yo!').pack()


        my_label = Label(second_frame, text="It's Friday Yo!").pack()

        rsi_len.pack()
        self.pack()
.
.
.
```